# C Server and Client - Segmentaion fault and showing garbage

Tags: c, server, client

I am programming a game of connect four server and client, and I need to transmit the game array to the client via a string.
I am trying to collect the array in a string variable, `playerBoard`, using `strcat`, but it seems that when it gets to the client, it displays garbage, and also, the server is showing me `Segmentation fault` as an error

Server:

```
 else
    {
      bzero(playersBoard, 100);
      int k, j;
      for( k = 0; k < HEIGTH; k++ )
    {
      for( j=0; j < WIDTH; j++ )
        {
          strcat(playersBoard, (char *)gameArray[k][j]);
          strcat(playersBoard, " ");
        }
    }
    strcat(playersBoard, "Now is your turn");
    printf("Players board is : \n%s\n", playersBoard);

      if(write(tdL.cl, playersBoard, 100) <= 0)
    {
      printf("[thread %d]\n", tdL.idThread);
      perror("[thread] Error at write\n");
    }
      else 
       printf("[thread %d] Message was sent with success\n", tdL.idThread);
      goto playerOneRetry;
    }
```

Client:

```
if (write (sd, message, sizeof(message)) <= 0)
{
  perror ("[client]Eroare la write() spre server.\n");
  return errno;
}

char message2[100];
  fflush(stdout);

  if (read (sd, message2, 100 ) < 0)
    {
      perror ("[client]Eroare la read() de la server.\n");
      return errno;
    }
  //writing message
  printf ("[client]Message received is : %s\n", message2);
```

Comment: "Showing garbage" is most likely an issue of not terminating a string, which lead to *undefined behavior*, and if you have UB (Undefined Behavior) then it's not a long step for you to have crashes.

Comment: But is it possible to use strcat how I use it?

Comment: It depends on what `gameArray[k][j]` is. What is it? Both the garbage and crashing problem can also be a case of using something as a pointer which is *not* a pointer, or by writing past the end of an array.

Comment: It's an array of characters

Comment: Then why do you cast it? Can you please show the actual declaration?

Comment: The declaration is `char gameArray[6][7]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `gameArray[k][j]` is a ***single*** character, it's not a string. You can not use it as argument in `strcat`. Trying to cast the character to `char *` will turn the encoded character into a pointer which is not going to point to a valid string. Using it as such will lead to *undefined behavior*.

You can append a single character to a string like e.g.

```
playersBoard[strlen(playersBoard)] = gameArray[k][j];
playersBoard[strlen(playersBoard) + 1] = '\0';
```

---

You should really keep an eye on the warnings the compiler will emit, and without the cast it should have said something. Warnings are often a sing of you doing something you should not be doing, and disabling them is usually not a good idea as it only hides the symptom and not the problem.

Also be careful with casting, in most situations it's considered a [*code smell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). If you find you need to cast something then you probably are doing something wrong as well.

The combination of warnings and casting is the worst of all, as like I said above you only *hide* the problem, but don't solve it.

Answer (score 2):

(char *)gameArray[k][j]

1e : (char *)gameArray[k][j] : why the cast ? gameArray[k][j] should be a 2 dim. array of type (char *). If you need to make the cast you probably defined it wrong which would cause the seg. fault.

2e : are you sure you don't overrun playersBoard ? That would cause it.

3e : bzero(playersBoard, 100); : the size of playersBoard is probably known. You should always try to avoid the static 100 and replace it by maybe : sizeof(playerBoard).

4e : You can prevent overrun of playersBoard. Using strncat and don't write more than you can. In the line of defensive programming .. you should.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that. Intially, the gnu de bugger called for the cast if the array's elements, but I'll ignore the warning.

Comment: If the compiler warns that the cast is needed, ignoring it will not help you. If gameArray is declared as gameArray[][][] you could try strcat(playersBoard, &gameArray[k][j][0] )